# Trigger ipcRenderer event from devtools in Electron BrowserWindow

Tags: electron

I need to trigger this event from devtools. It gets triggered when called from the main process (`js`) using `mainWindow.webContents.send('get-holdings', 'get holdings!');`

I have `webPrefences` set with `nodeIntegration: false` as there were `jquery` and `angular` errors if `nodeIntegration` was set to `true`.

For debugging, I want to do it from devtools console. I looking for the code that needs to be put into the devtools console to trigger the `get-holdings` event.

```
ipcRenderer.on('get-holdings', (event, arg) => {
 var holdings;
 $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/holdings', function(res){
    holdings = res.data;
    console.log(holdings);
    ipcRenderer.send('save-holdings', holdings);
 });
 console.log(arg);
})
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing ideas from the code in devtron, I solved it using this in the pre-load script

```
window.__electron = require('electron');
```

Then, I could simply do the following:

```
win = window.__electron.remote.getCurrentWindow()
win.webContents.send('get-holdings', 'get holdings!');
```